# Compilation issue with type alias of higherKinds

Tags: scala, type-inference, higher-kinded-types

I have a trait like

```
trait T{
  type F[_]
  def get[A](f: F[A]): A
}
```

But I cannot implement it

```
type Id[+A] = A // same as shapeless Id

object O extends T{
  type F[_] = Id[_]
  def get[A](f: F[A]): A = f // 
}
// error: type mismatch;
// found   : f.type (with underlying type O.F[A])
// required: A
//       def get[A](f: F[A]): A = f
//                                ^
```

(note I think i should work if I cast `f.asIntanceOf[A]` but I didn't try)

I have the same problem with Future:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
object O2 extends T{
  type F[_] = Future[_]
  def get[A](f: F[A]): A = Awaits.result(f, Duration.Inf)
}
// error: type mismatch;
// found   : scala.concurrent.Future[_$1] where type _$1
// required: scala.concurrent.Awaitable[A]
//   def get[A](f: F[A]): A = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
//                                         ^
```

Can someone explain to me what's happening? Why the compiler cannot understand the actual type `F[A]` is using the above type alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably wanted to write

```
type F[X] = Id[X]
```

and

```
type F[X] = Future[X]
```

Example:

```
trait T { type F[_]; def get[A](f: F[A]): A }
object Foo extends T { 
  type F[X] = List[X]
  def get[A](f: List[A]): A = f.head 
}
```

I assume that you will have to wait for Dotty and full support for type-lambdas until you can drop the redundant argument on both sides.

Comment: Thanks, that was it (damn me for missing that)